# How to detect when the power key is pressed in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how to detect when the user presses the power key on the keyboard.

I'm developing a kiosk application and I want to run a routine when the user want to force shut down the computer by pressing and holding the power key.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no methods that will be called when a user presses and holds the power key. That's directly handled in hardware and doesn't even get routed to the OS, much less to your application - it's the equivalent of pulling the power cord.

Your best bet is to create a "clean shut down" user preference key or temporary file that your app will remove as part of its normal shutdown procedure. When your app starts up, it can then check for it to see if the previous run was shut down normally, or had the rug yanked out from under it.

Oh, and since this is a kiosk - don't give users physical access to the power switch to begin with. Sometimes the simplest solutions are best!

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about that. Although the main purpose would have been to start an alarm to discourage the user from shutting down the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

From [Apple's Cocoa Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html):

> Note: Lower levels of the system trap
>   and handle some events early in the
>   event stream. These events are never
>   routed to a Cocoa application. These
>   events are generated by reserved keys
>   or key combinations, such as the power
>   and media-eject keys.

You can make your application perform some action and/or prevent a shutdown with `applicationShouldTerminate`, somewhat covered at the [Graceful Application Termination](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AppArchitecture/Tasks/GracefulAppTermination.html) doc page. This won't be exactly the same as just responding to the key event, though.

You can also use the [`NSApplicationPresentationDisableSessionTermination`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html) flag to just disable logout and shutdown.

Comment: None of that will disable shutdown by pressing and holding the power button. That's like pulling the power cord, there's nothing that can be done in software to prevent it.

Comment: Good point. I must have missed the "and holding" part of the question.

Comment: Thanks guys. It seems there is not much I can do to prevent hardware shut down. It sort of makes sense, I guess it is the last resort if the system hangs badly.